# Post apocalyptic comic with giant traveling worm-like train of people that everyone fights to be on top of

Tags: story-identification, comics

I don't recall the circumstances, just the train of people. The current presiding winner of the constant and ongoing battle-royale would stand on top of the writhing giant worm made out of 1000's of people, that stood a couple of stories high even when laying flat, and ride it around the city like it were a single beast. It was a comic or graphic novel that I borrowed from someone in the late 80's or early 90's so that's about all I recall about the story. Does that ring any bells for anyone? Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I remember something similar from the end of a comic by [Rick Veitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Veitch), maybe [The One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_One_(comics)). It ends with a human pyramid where everyone fights to get to the top.